# Parsing HTML (get text/string between tags)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have this:

```
<div class="ResultItem">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="result">
            <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx" onclick="trackClick(this, '117', 'http\x3a\x2f\x2fmsdn.microsoft.com\x2fen-us\x2flibrary\x2fsystem.windows.uielement.aspx', '1');"><b>UIElement</b> Class &#40;System.Windows&#41;</a>&nbsp;
            <div class="ResultDescription"><b>UIElement</b> is a base class for WPF core level implementations building on Windows Presentation Foundation &#40;WPF&#41; elements and basic presentation characteristics.</div>
            <div class="ResultUrl">msdn.microsoft.com&#47;en-us&#47;library&#47;sy<wbr><a class="wbr"></a>stem.windows.<b>uielement</b>.aspx</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to extract data from the `<a>(grab this string)</a>` and `<div class="ResultDescription">(grab data</div>`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet long term is to use a dedicated HTML parsing library not custom string manipulation. There's a trunk version of [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) called [HAPPhone](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77494#) that works on Windows Phone 7. You will have to download it manually from codeplex, but it still beats having to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to read the MSDN website, they have an actual web service API for that

http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx

So screen scraping isn't necessary. Just add a reference to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

If, (and only if!), your html is a valid XHTML you can use any XML parser to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what BrokenGlass mentioned, the overwhelming answer to [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) is to use libraries like HtmlAgilityPack, for the phone this would mean things like HAPPphone

Answer (score 0):

If your parsing task is just for small length string then , You can parse string with 'html' content using javascript.
following line of code will use regular expression to replace html tags and provides normal text.

```
//Javascript
var normal_text = html_string.replace(/(<.*?>)/ig,"");
```